# How do I prevent filling the same details repeatedly when entering data from a CSV file using Python Selenium and Xpath?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
with open('C://pyhtonprograms//flipkartinfo.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader (csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:

        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/checkout/init?view=GROCERY&loginFlow=false")
        time.sleep(4)

        name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[1]/input')
        name.send_keys(line[0])
        time.sleep(1)

        phone = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[2]/input')
        phone.send_keys(line[1])
        time.sleep(1)

        pincode = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/form/div/div[3]/div[1]/input')
        pincode.send_keys(line[2])
        time.sleep(1)

        locality = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/form/div/div[3]/div[2]/input')
        locality.send_keys(line[3])
        time.sleep(1)

        address = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/div[2]/div/form/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/textarea')
        address.send_keys(line[4])
        time.sleep(2)
```

I am entering the data from a csv file to a website and there are more steps to be continued but the loop is getting stuck in the same process again and again, repeatedly entering the same details from the same file.

So, i want to ask that how can i stop that details to filling repeatedly and continue the next step in the script and i also want to enter different details from my csv file for the next loop.

Comment: you should add your code and more details for other to understand [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: did brother check if you could help?

Comment: those are some awful xpath paths.  You may want to learn how to write xpath queries to make your life easier.  Queries can be easier to read and maintain. Static paths will break the second the DOM changes.
this site is a lifesaver for me. https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Read about random numbers:

```
import random
print(random.randint(0,9))
```

This will print a random number between 0 and 9. I assume that you have many lines in your CSV file. So you will have to choose a random line and enter its data in your test.

You can create random words like this:

```
abc = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
word = ''
for i in range(10):
    word += abc[randomint(26)]
```

Comment: using random numbers wouldn't help with the loop repeating info over and over.  I don't have an account with flipkart. and the UI doesn't seem to match what @Nitin Nawani posted.  The 1st prompt I'm seeing is email/mobile, not "name".  But "container" seems to be the main frame/div for the website.

Comment: So create a random word, take a look at my answer again.

Comment: @Nitin didn't say they were trying to test random keywords.  _they have not posted a sufficient example either_

But yes, this is a quick, easy, and readable way to generate random 10 character words.